# How to clear the input field (remove the search term) after the search?

Tags: reactjs, routes

Here's my App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Toolbar from './components/Navigation/Toolbar/Toolbar';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage/Homepage';
import CategoryPage from './containers/CategoryPage/CategoryPage';
import SingleMealPage from './containers/SingleMealPage/SingleMealPage';
import SearchPage from './containers/SearchPage/SearchPage';
import AboutUsPage from './components/AboutUs/AboutUsPage';
import ContactPage from './components/Contact/ContactPage';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: ''
  }

  searchTermHandler = (mealName) => {
    if(mealName !== '') {
      const queryParams = [];
      queryParams.push(encodeURIComponent(mealName));
      const queryString = queryParams.join();

      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/searchResults',
        search: '?' + queryString
      });

      this.setState({searchTerm: ''});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Toolbar          
          clickSearch={() => this.searchTermHandler(this.state.searchTerm)}
          changeSearch={(event) => this.setState({searchTerm: event.target.value})} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/category" component={CategoryPage} />
            <Route path="/singleMeal" component={SingleMealPage} />
            <Route path="/searchResults" component={SearchPage} />
            <Route path="/aboutUs" component={AboutUsPage} />
            <Route path='/contact' component={ContactPage} />
            <Route path="/" component={Homepage} />
          </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

What is the problem?
When I input a search term and click on a button, it takes me to the SearchPage but with a search term still present in the input field. Line `this.setState({searchTerm: ''});` inside the `searchTermHandler` function clears the input value, but it doesn't remove the plain text in the input field.

Furthermore, I don't even have to click on a search button for this problem to occur. It's enough to navigate to, for example, CategoryPage and see that the search term entered on the Homepage is still present on the CategoryPage.

This looks to me like a simple problem, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Just in case you need it, I'll post my Search and Toolbar components:

```
import classes from './Search.css';

const search = (props) => (
  <div className={classes.Search}>
    <input type="text" placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={props.change} />
    <button type="submit" onClick={props.clicked}><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>
);

export default search;
```

```
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Toolbar.css';
import Search from '../../UI/Search/Search';

const toolbar = (props) => (
  <header className={classes.Toolbar}>
    <Search
      placeholder="Search recipes"
      clicked={props.clickSearch}
      change={props.changeSearch} />
  </header>
);

export default toolbar;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox link for reference so that we have reproducible code.

Comment: Perhaps Your input value should be searchTerm input={props.searchTerm}

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass down the search value to the input field :

```
<Toolbar searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm} ...
<Search value={props.searchTerm} ...
<input value={props.value} ...
```

Comment: Yeah, this does solve the first problem (click on a search button). Any ideas how to solve the second one (navigating from one page to another)?